# Is it possible to refactor generic parameter constraints out of the type/function definition?

Tags: .net, f#

Suppose I have a generic type with a long list of generic parameter constraints:

```
type Gen<'A when cond1 and cond2 and ...>(a:'A) =
    member this.A = a
```

Moreover, the same list of constraints appears for other types in the project. Repeating the same list of constraints every time creates a lot of noise. What's worse, it hampers extensibility and functional design, as functions acting on `Gen.A` will need to redeclare these constraints. The same is not true for methods of `Gen`.

Is it possible to refactor these constraints out of the type definition? That would be something akin to creating a type of types or a predicate on types.

EDIT: The concrete case is as follows, though this likely will not be helpful. I have a triplet of abstract classes `Product`, `Viewer` and `Producer`. The parametrization is

```
Product<'Viewer> 
Viewer<'Product> 
Producer<'Product, 'Viewer where 'Product:> Product<'Viewer> and 'Viewer:>Viewer<'Product> and 'Viewer : (new : unit -> 'Viewer)>
```

and it is the last one that irks me. Viewer compares different instances of Product, and Producer produces Products from a data stream and adds them to appropriate Viewers . Different kinds of product are done by inheritance from Product, with corresponding Viewers deriving from Viewer.

This is a bit of a clusterfuck but is I believe the cleanest way to do it without sacrificing performance or static type checking. For example, the whole generic structure can be thrown away if one changes the abstract method of Viewer from generic `AddProduct: 'Product->unit` to taking a parameter from the abstract class: `AddProduct: Product->unit` (and making analogous modifications to other methods). This will however make it so that one can add a wrong kind of Product to a Viewer, and it will throw only at runtime.

This problem of creating a generic tuple of types that will work together is I believe without a really clean solution in NET.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what exactly those conditions are? My gut feeling is that you're hit by trying to be too generic for your own good.

Comment: Depending on what you want exactly, you can probably write an interface.

Comment: @scrwtp I added some details of the case.

Comment: @arbil don't forget the upvotes!

Comment: @RubenBartelink Sure, done so now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such mechanism in F#.  You could possibly limit the functions which need to know about the constraints by having a static factory function which constrains the values with which the class could be constructed and then pass all functions which depend on the constraint as parameters.  This obviously has some severe drawbacks in the case where the constrains on the parameter really are needed in a significant number of functions.  There are probably other options here, all of which, I think, will end up being some form of isolation for the parts of the class which require the type constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing a type constrained like this would irk me as well. It's almost a sure-tell sign something went wrong somewhere in the design.

First thing that strikes me as odd is why do you need a `Product<'Viewer>`? I wouldn't expect a product to know anything about viewers, so it seems to me that whatever the functionality is in product that would make use of 'Viewer, it could probably live outside that type.

The second thing that for me has little business to exist as a type constraint, is `'Viewer : (new : unit -> 'Viewer)`. If you want Producer to be able to create instances of Viewer, you can get it by simply passing in a `makeViewer: unit -> 'Viewer`.

With that, I imagine you could easily get something like:

```
Product 
Viewer<'Product> 
Producer<'Product, 'Viewer where 'Viewer:>Viewer<'Product>>
```

Finally, if you only cared about an IViewer interface, you could have something like:

```
Producer<'Product>(makeViewer: unit -> IViewer<'Product> ...)
```

and a lot less headache with types.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. In one way or another I've already considered all this (I in particular agree `Product<'Viewer>` is undesirable but have not found a way to eliminate the dependence without taking a small performance hit), but you've given me some food for thought.